# Extracting from tuple then sort

Tags: python

```
students = [

        ('tiffany', 'A', 15),

        ('jane', 'B', 10),

        ('ben', 'C', 8),

        ('simon', 'A', 21),

        ('john', 'A', 15),

        ('jimmy', 'F', 1),

        ('charles', 'C', 9),

        ('freddy', 'D', 4),

        ('dave', 'B', 12)]
```

I am suppose to return a tuple that has names with fewer than 6 characters. `('jane', 'ben', 'simon', 'john', 'jimmy', 'dave')`
My idea is to filter first then sort it with `sorted()`

However there is an error.

```
x = filter(lambda students: len(students) < 4, students)
sorted(x, key= x, reverse = True)
```

Comment: This is a typo, it should be `lambda student: len(student) < 4` instead of `lambda students: len(student) < 4`. And you don't need the `key` argument. `key=x` is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator expression to filter out the students whose names are lesser than 6 characters and then sort them with `sorted`, like this

```
print [student[0] for student in students if len(student[0]) < 6]
# ['jane', 'ben', 'simon', 'john', 'jimmy', 'dave']
```

Comment: the order should be ('jane', 'ben', 'simon', 'john', 'jimmy', 'dave') as 'jane' is from the first tuple then follow by ben. I think we can elminate the sorted here. But how do I do it if such that the names are extracted in the order of the tuples ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are sorting, when your output is clearly not sorted. You can make a tuple using the `tuple` object.

```
print tuple(s[0] for s in students if len(s[0]) < 6)
```

Comment: This is almost correct but it returns me ('simon', 'john', 'dave', 'jane', 'ben', 'jimmy') instead of ('jane', 'ben', 'simon', 'john', 'jimmy', 'dave')

Comment: If you want the order from the dictionary, then that is not possible because items are stored arbitrarily inside a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter on character

```
>>> students
[('tiffany', 'A', 15), ('jane', 'B', 10), ('ben', 'C', 8), ('simon', 'A', 21), ('john', 'A', 15), ('jimmy', 'F', 1), ('charles', 'C', 9), ('freddy', 'D', 4), ('dave', 'B', 12)]
>>> x = filter(lambda student: len(student[0]) < 6, students)
>>> z = sorted(x, key=lambda y:y[0], reverse = True)
>>> [y[0] for y in z]
['simon', 'john', 'jimmy', 'jane', 'dave', 'ben']
```

Comment: You will get an empty list for this.